# How can I convert pygame that can display image to apk with buildozer

Tags: python, android, pygame, apk, buildozer

So far I have been able to convert pygame into apk with buildozer and everything works fine including the animation. But when I add images like jpeg and png it will not work anymore. The app will crash after the loading screen. And when I remove the image and deploy it again the app will work perfectly fine again.

I have googled for days now but nothing helps. In the spec file I have included png ang jpeg but still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the error message using adb logcat. Just download and install adb in any directory and open cmd in that directory. After that, connect your mobile to pc using a usb cable. Then type the following command:

adb logcat | to python

Make sure that USB Debugging is enabled in your android device developer options. Now a pop-up will ask you to allow usb debug by this PC. Click OK.
This will give you all the errors or messages you generally see in the Python console once you run the app on your phone.

You can then solve that issue easily and rebuild your app with buildozer.